# Custom sort to sort particular field in huge data set

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, csh

I have a scenario.. where I need to do custom sort
In 4th column ... these are the possible values.
`TUN`
`PB`
`TP`

I am able to use sort for 1st and 2nd fields for the whole data set
File sizes are > 500MB so, performance also should be considered.
but for 4th field .. I have to create a custom sort in such a way that output would be in this order for 4th field.
`TUN`
`PB`
`TP`

Input data:

```
0022|||PB||||||||||||||||
0022|||TN|0|||||||||||||||||||||
```

Expected output is

```
0022||TN|0|||||||||||||||||||||
0022|||PB||||L|||||||||||||||||||||||
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Use `awk` to add another column, 1 for TUNES, 2 for PLAYBACK, 3 for TRICKPLAY, and then sort on that column and use `cut` to remove it after.

Comment: @Shawn : how does adding new columns help ? I already have 23 columns of data.. just in 4th fields, one of this field would be present. Since I am not getting it in desired order and since sorting alphabetically does not help, custom sort has to be done

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show some example input, the command you use for sorting and the actual and expected output.

Comment: You can then do a numeric sort on that column to get the order you want.

Comment: @Shawn:Numeric sort does not give us required order

Comment: Your value descriptions, input and output are not consistent. Do you want to sort by the 4th field only or do you also need to sort by other fields as second, third... key field? Do all lines have the same number of fields?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is an idiom called *decorate-sort-undecorate*. The idea is to add a column with sortable values based on the data you want to sort by, sort on that, and then remove the extra column to get the original data in the correct order.

Example:

```sh
$ cat sample.txt
a|b|c|PLAYBACK|x
d|e|f|TUNES|y
g|h|i|TRICKPLAY|z
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|"; order["TUNES"] = 1
               order["PLAYBACK"] = 2; order["TRICKPLAY"] = 3 }
       { print order[$4], $0 }
      '  sample.txt | sort -t'|' -k1,1n | cut -d'|' -f 2-
d|e|f|TUNES|y
a|b|c|PLAYBACK|x
g|h|i|TRICKPLAY|z
```

You'll have to adjust the sort keys to get the final ordering you want (You mention sorting on other columns, but nothing about what order they should be used as sort keys in), of course.

Comment: Side note: It bugs me to no end that `sort` and `cut` use different options for the column delimiter. Consistency, thy name is not Unix.

Comment: The script could be simplified and made independent from the actual number of columns by inserting the extra column before the first column, e.g. `awk 'BEGIN {...} { print order[$4],$0 }' sample.txt | sort | cut -d'|' -f 2-`

Comment: @Bodo Good suggestion.